# How to change appearance of jquery datetimepicker , add buttons and custom arrows:

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am required to design a datetimepicker which should have a white background, custom arrows and also in the bottom it must have buttons, i should also be able to change minutes and seconds.. similar to angular js . but the problem is i am not using angular js. can we do it just with html css and jquery?
Any help will be appreciated as I am new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this info](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#theming) for possibilities.

Comment: Hi Paul T. , Thank you for your answer. But I am not looking just for datepicker it has to be for datetimepicker. Although I tried the one that you gave but it didn't work....

Comment: Well, you can also use the browser to inspect the element to see what CSS classes are used. Whatever you change needs to be _after_ the point of linking the datetimepicker's CSS file, not before.

Comment: Thankyou  for your help Paul, for now I have been asked to retain the widget without any modification.